# Why can't I edit the question I am reviewing?

Tags: bug, review-queues

I'm perusing the First Post Review queue, and noticed that the edit link is greyed out for the [question that I am reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5770674), not only in the edit window, but also when I go to the actual question outside of the review.

[image]

As you can see, the edit button is unavailable. However it appears that it is only for this question, as I can edit other questions. The question is not deleted, or locked.

Is it because that it is a new question? Or is it because the user is currently editing the question. I was going to indent the top line of code, to make the code block complete, because I don't really see anything else wrong with the question . I imagine that this restriction would make it difficult to progress with the badges to do with editing questions in the review queue.

Comment: There is an existing edit suggestion which blocks other suggestions

Comment: Ah, but I'm in the first post queue, not the low quality post queue, so I can't apply that suggested edit. Does this mean that editing is locked to all users until that edit is applied?

Comment: Only to those that need to suggest edits

Comment: What's the rep limit for that?

Comment: The cutoff is 2000: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges