# How to review questions with pending edit

Tags: discussion, review-queues

This question is somewhat related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271374/why-cant-i-edit-the-question-i-am-reviewing?s=2%7C0.1636) post.

While doing a review (*first posts* queue for example), sometimes the question I review has problems with its formatting, that could be fixed by editing. And as another reviewer came to the same conclusion, there is already a suggested edit in peer review, meaning the `edit`button is greyed out for me.

**Now, how should I proceed in this case?**

I can not edit the question, and I do neither want to comment, up- or down-vote, as it would not help in my opinion.

By now, I click `No action needed`, as the pending edit is likely to solve what I criticise about the post - but I can not know whether the edit will be approved or rejected, and as I do not have the privileges required to have a look at the edit yet, I can not judge for myself. Or should I just skip the question for later review?

Comment: If the down-voter would be so kind to explain his reasoning I would be glad. I can not see whats wrong with the question. I can not see anything that might be unclear. I could also not find any similar question on MSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always *skip* the review.

Another option would be to choose *"No action needed"*, while you keep the post open in a separate tab, to make sure the edit gets accepted, or to re-apply the edit if it got unjustly rejected.